# How to show press down (:active) effect before lifting the finger?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to show the :active CSS effect on mobile devices before the user lifts their finger. Currently using :active and it shows its effect after the finger was lifted. One of the few sites I found that has the effect I like are Amazon's buttons.

Comment: Try button:active:hover {}

Comment: Possibly use `:focus` if you want the element to remain active until another element is clicked on?

Comment: button:active:hover {} does not work. I also use <a> instead of <button>. :focus works but it only shows after the finger was raised.

Comment: @enzobruno check my answer below that works. If it still isn't working in your mobile browser I'll need more information.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:hover:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href=src"">link</a>
```

This seemed to do the trick for me! Apparently the active has to be after the hover based on how CSS evaluates its code.

If you are using Javascript use the onmousedown event.

```js
function mouseDown() {
  document.getElementById("myA").style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<a id="myA" onmousedown="mouseDown()"> Link
</a>
```